slack response_type "in_channel" not working
I ran into a super weird issue. I'm trying to send the message to everyone in the channel using the response_url by setting response_type to in_channel following the official document.
When I do this, it works.
export async function respondUsingResponseUrlAsync({
    accessToken,
    responseUrl,
    message,
    blocks,
}: {
    accessToken: string;
    responseUrl: string;
    message: string;
    blocks?: unknown;
}) {
    const payload = {
        text: message,
        blocks,
        response_type: 'in_channel',
    };
    await fetch(responseUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });
}

But when I do this, it doesn't. I verified that I passed true to isPublic and console.log the payload, it has the response_type set to in_channel correctly.
export async function respondUsingResponseUrlAsync({
    accessToken,
    responseUrl,
    message,
    blocks,
    isPublic,
}: {
    accessToken: string;
    responseUrl: string;
    message: string;
    blocks?: unknown;
    isPublic?: boolean;
}) {
    const payload = {
        text: message,
        blocks,
        response_type: isPublic ? 'in_channel' : undefined,
    };
    await fetch(responseUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });
}

Never encountered such weird behavior. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!
searched online, didn't find anything useful.
